# Failde Install MySQL Server 8.0.14

Tags: mysql, sql, installation

I tried to install MySQL Server 8.0.14.
The install is failed
I get a message:
 "This application requires Visual Studio 2015 x64 Redistributable. Please install the Redistributable then run this installer again."

But I have already Visual Studio 2017

So, I do not know how to solve the problem.
Please, help me
Thank you

Comment: Would have liked to see OS version but presuming Windows 10 ? Also please could you correct your post title to 'Error on' or 'Failed' or something !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd advise you to follow the advice from the error message. The 2015 Visual Studio Redistributable can be downloaded from this [Microsoft page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145), or you can find it on this [redistributable list](https://www.itechtics.com/microsoft-visual-c-redistributable-versions-direct-download-links/#Microsoft_Visual_C_Redistributable_2015)

In general, the error log is right.

Comment: Thank you!
It helped!
Today and yesterday I made my first steps to use and t learn MySQL, so I have a stuck.
But you helped me.
The problem is solved.
I go ahead.

Comment: does not seem to help as cannot install the suggested redistributable [0AF0:39EC][2019-01-27T19:48:40]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true.
[0AF0:39EC][2019-01-27T19:48:40]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0
[0AF0:12D8][2019-01-27T19:48:52]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 10 I found the only answer was to completely uninstall every Visual Studio Redistributable (easy via Control Panel > Apps, no fancy stuff needed in Windows 10 registry) and then attempt the MySQL install. [sidenote here is to run Python install as Admin].
This is because the required VS Redistributable installs themselves could not install as referenced by VS log:

```
[0AF0:39EC][2019-01-27T19:48:40]i052: Condition 'VersionNT >= v6.0 OR (VersionNT = v5.1 AND ServicePackLevel >= 2) OR (VersionNT = v5.2 AND ServicePackLevel >= 1)' evaluates to true. [0AF0:39EC][2019-01-27T19:48:40]i199: Detect complete, result: 0x0 [0AF0:12D8][2019-01-27T19:48:52]e000: Error 0x80070666: Cannot install a product when a newer version is installed
```

This then gave obvious requirements to get the MySql required redistributables but they now installed without hassle and a very familiar MySql install process completed.

Installed VS Redist 2017 following this and MySql server is fine.